How to validate the current state derived using watcher equals the state retrieved by a list request in kubernetes (python)?
I am using watchers to build up an internal representation of a list of custom resources.
Now I want to validate that my wachter implementation is working and had the idea to use resource_versions to check for consistency.
The docs specify:

API clients may only compare two resource versions for equality

Therefore, I planned to send another list request and compare the resource version of the last received watch event with the current resource version in the list response.
Surprisingly, they are unequal (although there were no changes in the meantime) and I would like to understand why?
The same happens if I send multiple List requests, I always get different resource versions. How should I compare resource version for equality?

What kind of custom resources are you dealing with? Depending on CR implementation, they might be constantly updated by their controller, resulting in everchanging resourceVersion

It is my one custom resource, just for testing for now. There is no operate etc listening or doing something with this resource.
Furthermore, I also started a watcher on every of the resource version, and there are no updates in the stream.
